# Data concurrency because doctrine use SET column_name = value instead of increment it like SET column_name = column_name + difference_value

Tags: symfony, concurrency, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine2 with symfony2. I have problem about data concurrency. Here is my case.

I create a website for ecommerce. Lets say I have product A with quantity = 5. Customer X buy 4 items of product A and Customer Y buy 2 items of product A at the same time.
For customer X case, doctrine will query product A and the initial quantity is 5. Then doctrine update the quantity and set it to 1 (5 - 4).
For customer Y case, the initial quantity of product A is still 5 because customer Y and customer X buy that product at the same time, so they get the same initial quantity. Then doctrine update the quantity to 3 (5 - 2).

If doctrine2 provides some way to generate query by increment it like SET column_name = column_name + difference_value instead of SET column_name = value, it would be a nice solution. But from what I got, doctrine2 always generate query using SET column_name = value.

Is there any solution or workaround instead of locking the table ? By locking the table so it means that customer Y have to wait until customer X finish his transaction. Lets say that there are 100 customers buy that product at the same time, the performance will be very bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use doctrine transactions. There is many ways to solve your problem.
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Comment: Yes I am using transaction too for that case. But because they buy the same product and at the same time, they get the same initial quantity and not the latest updated quantity.

Comment: How about optimistic locking? If exception occurred reload product from DB and try again to update data.

Comment: Yes i think it can solve my problem. But i'm still wondering how about the impact to the performance. Like for example what if 10 or 20 customers buy the same product at the same time, so it has to reload product again and again. Thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: Maybe you shoud push operations to some sort of message queue? Like rabbitmq? If you can't - just scale up your stack and keep calm or find workaround :)